# Loop through an array in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through an array in Bash when using rclone. I have set up an array of paths, and I'm looping through them, but I also want to echo the path name in the console window. When I run my code, because the paths have spaces in them, the echo command shows each part of the path, instead of the whole path. Here is my code;

```
folder[0]="a path here"
folder[1]="another path here"
folder[2]="another path here"
folder[3]="another path here"

for item in ${folder[*]}; do
  echo "syncing $item ..."
  rclone copy ~/"Documents/$item" Box:"$item" -u -vv --syslog
done
```

What I see is

```
syncing 'a' ... 
syncing 'path' ... 
syncing 'here' ... 
syncing 'another' ...
syncing 'path' ...
syncing 'here' ...
```

What I want to see is the full path string. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I guess it's the referencing in the `folder[*]` causing me the problem.

Comment: do this `"${folder[@]}"` make sure you wrap the array in double qutoes

Comment: More info, when variable are put inside single quotes, they are not expanded.

Comment: I tried using the @ symbol before, but it did not work, I guess the magic part was the inclusion of the quote marks around the variable. Thanks

Comment: Quoting `${folder[@]}` is the sole reason `@` exists along with `*`. More generally, parameter expansions should *always* be quoted until you discover a reason not too.